# Animation based on ViewPager offset

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-animation

I have a `ViewPager` which has 5 pages. And I have another TextView `tvInstruction` which is below ViewPager and it gets texts from the array based on the ViewPager's `position`.

I was able to achieve this so far: To animate this TextView's alpha property based on the ViewPager's `positionOffset`. So when page comes from right (when swiped left) `tvInstruction` alpha property decreases gradually and when two pages of the ViewPager are equally visible on the screen alpha property of the `tvInstruction` becomes `0f`. And then again it gradually gains alpha moving to 1f when the swipe is done.

**What I want to achieve**: 
In the middle of the swipe when alpha property of the TextView becomes `0f` I want the `tvInstruction` to get the other `String` from the `mInstructions` array based on the swipe. And it should work even when I swipe almost to the next page but without removing my finger returning to the current page -> `tvInstruction` should change its text to other text from the array and then when returning to the current page It should change to the current page's text.

What I noticed is that `position` argument of the `onPageScrolled()` method gets incremented/decremented when the swipe is *complete* not in the middle. That is the problem I am asking you to help me to solve.

This is from my MainActivity:

```
private float alphaVal;
private int mPageNumber;
private mInstructions[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // "diff" to determine the swipe 
    float diff = positionOffset - mLastPositionOffset;
    // "alphaVal" based on the positionOffset
    alphaVal = (1f - positionOffset * 2);
    if (diff > 0) {
        System.out.println("swipe left");
        tvInstruction.setAlpha(Math.abs(alphaVal));

        // This is where the magic happens 
        if (alphaVal < 0 && mPageNumber == position) {
            tvInstruction.setText(mInstructions[mPageNumber + 1]);
            mPageNumber++;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("swipe right");
        tvInstruction.setAlpha(Math.abs(alphaVal));

        // This is where the magic happens
        if (alphaVal > 0 && mPageNumber == position) {
            tvInstruction.setText(mInstructions[mPageNumber - 1]);
            mPageNumber--;
        }
    }
    mLastPositionOffset = positionOffset;
}
```

If there is any ambiguous place in the questions, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: tried `ViewPager.PageTransformer`?

Comment: Hmm, no, never heard of it... googling it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @psking's advice, I was able to achieve the desired animation with `ViewPager.PageTransformer`. Here is how I did:

```
private mInstructions[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
@Override
public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
    int pagePosition = Integer.parseInt((String) page.getTag());
    float absPosition = Math.abs(position);
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    if (position <= -1.0f || position >= 1.0f) {
        // page is not visible here - stop running any animations
    } else if (position == 0.0f) {
        // page is selected -- reset any view if necessary
        tvInstruction.setAlpha(1f);
    } else {
        // page is currently being swiped -- perform animations here
        // get the alpha property values based on the `property` value of the swipe
        float alpha = Math.abs(1f - 2 * absPosition);
        // playing with TextView {tvInstruction} and NextButton {btnNextAndDone}
        playWithTextView(pagePosition, position, alpha);
        playWithNextButton(pagePosition, position, alpha);
    }
}

private void playWithTextView(int pagePosition, float position, float alpha) {
    // setting the alpha property of the TextView
    tvInstruction.setAlpha(alpha);
    // Use only odd numbered pages.
    if (pagePosition % 2 == 1) {
        if (position > 0.5f) {
            tvInstruction.setText(mInstructions[pagePosition - 1]);
        } else if (position < 0.5f && position > -0.5f) {
            tvInstruction.setText(mInstructions[pagePosition]);
        } else if (position < -0.5f) {
            tvInstruction.setText(mInstructions[pagePosition + 1]);
        }
    }
}

private void playWithNextButton(int pagePosition, float position, float alpha) {
    if (pagePosition == 3) {
        if (position < 0) {
            btnNextAndDone.setAlpha(alpha);
            if (position < -0.5f) {
                setNextButtonFeatures();
            } else if (position > -0.5f) {
                setDoneButtonFeatures();
            }
        }
    }
}
```